# Python regex to extract tokens

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find all the tokens which look either like `abc_rty` or `abc_45` or `abc09_23k` or `abc09-K34` or `4535`. The tokens shouldn't start with `_` or `-` or numbers.

I am not making any progress and have even lost the progress that I did. This is what I have now:

```
r'(?<!0-9)[(a-zA-Z)+]_(?=a-zA-Z0-9)|(?<!0-9)[(a-zA-Z)+]-(?=a-zA-Z0-9)\w+'
```

To make the question more clear here is an example:
If i have a string as follows:

```
    D923-44 43 uou 08*) %%5 89ANB -iopu9 _M89 _97N hi_hello
```

Then it shall accept

```
    D923-44 and 43 and uou and hi_hello
```

It should ignore

```
    08*) %%5 89ANB -iopu9 _M89 _97N
```

I might have missed some cases but i think the text would be enough. Apologies if its not

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "shouldn't start with a number, but can have only numbers"? Also, what characters are allowed before or after a token (in other words, what separates a token from the surrounding text)?

Comment: I meant that it cannot be 89AM but the token can be a solitary number like 89

Comment: So, you're looking to extract the numbers from the valid tokens?

Comment: No. Suppose i have a line with space acting as a delimiter like "fus9f23-44 24 uou *)*) 808*)*8&^^&%%5  89ANB -iopu9 _897M _ui7 khi_hello" then it should pick "fus9f23-44" , "24"  and "khi_hello"

Comment: Why shouldn't it catch `uou`, `808` or the other numbers like `8` or `5`?

Comment: Yeah "uou" should be picked but not 808 because it has *)*88&^^..... concatenated to it.

Comment: So, the answer to the second question in my first comment is that the tokens are always separated by whitespace?

Comment: Tokens are separated by space but not by underscore or hyphen

Comment: OK, thanks (although I don't get why you wrote "but not by underscore or hyphen" - neither of those are spaces). For the benefit of other readers, it would be a good idea if you edited your question to update it with these requirements. Not everyone reads all the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(\d+|[A-Za-z][\w_-]*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/9WJTQzMEfu6MwvNZ)

split the line with a space delimiter then run this REGEX through the line to filter.

- `^` is the start of the line
- `\d` means digits `[0-9]`
- `+` means one or more
- `|` means OR
- `[A-Za-z]` first character must be a letter
- `[\w_-]*` There can be any alphanumeric _ + character after it or nothing at all.
- `$` means the end of the line

The flow of the REGEX is shown in the chart I provided, which somewhat explains how it's happening.

However, ill explain basically it checks to see if it's all digits OR it starts with a letter(upper/lower) then after that letter it checks for any alphanumeric _ + character until the end of the line.

Comment: This does not do at all what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Split on spaces then filter by this regex.  I think it works..  (or at least, is very close.  Matching `.` near the end, I think needs to be more restrictive)

Comment: @Izkata: No. It allows many "illegal" matches. Nishant only allows alphanumerics (plus hyphen/underscore) to match. (The question was unclear on this previously, but the comments and the current edit made that clear).

Comment: @TimPietzcker I updated. I will also update with a regex that parses through the whitespaces.

Comment: @progenhard: Could you explain it to me what this regex translates to.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work as desired:

```
regex = re.compile(r"""
    (?<!\S)   # Assert there is no non-whitespace before the current character
    (?:       # Start of non-capturing group:
     [^\W\d_] # Match either a letter
     [\w-]*   # followed by any number of the allowed characters
    |         # or
     \d+      # match a string of digits.
    )         # End of group
    (?!\S)    # Assert there is no non-whitespace after the current character""", 
    re.VERBOSE)
```

See it on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/aR7fW9).